# htaccess - Redirecting URL with parameter to same URL with another parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have some sort of a web-site and I've come along with a problem.

Basically all I want is to temporarily redirect any link that contains a specific parameter to the same link but with another parameter. I have made some research about .htaccess and parameters but I can't figure out the syntax.

Example:

```
From: 
http://domain.com/link?___store=default

To:
http://domain.com/link?___store=english
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following directives to your .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^___store=(default)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?___store=english%2 [R=301,L]
```

Hope this will help for you. :)

Comment: It works! Thank you! There is a little problem that it redirects to the root folder. Something like `/var/www/html/www.domain.ro/link?___store=default`

Comment: Try little manipulations in above code. I am sure you will do it :)